# MySQL search for multiple keywords and order by best match

Tags: php, mysql, search

I currently have a tag system for my blog. 
Each blog is inserted in the blog table, and the tags are inserted in the tag table.
The tag table has a column blog_id to link each tag to a blog item.

So let's say we have:

```
Blog table:
id - name 
20 - a nice blog post about product x

Tag table:
id - blog_id - tag
12 - 20 - nice
13 - 20 - product x
```

I have a search function that searches through the tags based on a search string and that works fine.

But I would like to expand the query to search for multiple tags, and order it by the best match. Searching for multiple tags will not be a problem, because I could just explode the search string and loop through it, but ordering it by the best match is something I can not figure out.

So let's say I have 3 blog posts, with each the following tags: 
1. sunny, in-ear, earphones, review
2. pear, out-ear, earphones, review
3. pear, in-ear, earphones, review

And a user searches for "pear in-ear earphones", I would like the order of the result to be:
3. (because 3 tags match)
1. (because 2 tags match)
2. (because 1 tags match)

This is what the query looks like:

```
SELECT `b`.* 
FROM (`blog` b) 
WHERE (
    b.name LIKE '%pear in-ear earphones%' 
    OR 
    b.id IN ( 
        SELECT bt.blog_id 
        FROM blog_tags bt 
        WHERE bt.tag LIKE '%pear in-ear earphones%' 
        AND bt.blog_id = b.id 
        ) 
    ) 
ORDER BY `b`.`date` desc
```

Who could help me out? 
I've looked at "Full Text Search" but that is not an option, because my table is InnoDB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL 5.6 has FULLTEXT mechanism for InnoDB (but I didn't check it myself yet, therefore that's all I can say about it...)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my server runs MySQL client version: 5.5.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally love using [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for text matching. You can create these complex formulas that will weight matches in the name higher than matches in the tags or vice versa. It also matches pluralizations too. So if I search `butterflies` it will find the `butterfly` matches.

Here's another query that may help you with order blog tags by frequency. This query will get all of the blog items with at least one match in the tags. It will order by the number of tags that matches

```
SELECT *
FROM blog b
JOIN (
    SELECT blog_id, COUNT(*) as matches 
    FROM tags 
    WHERE tag in ('pear', 'in-ear', 'earphones') 
    GROUP BY blog_id
) t
ON t.blog_id = b.blog_id
ORDER BY matches desc
```

You can add the number of matches for a particular string like this:

```
SELECT *,
    t.matches + 
    COALESCE((LENGTH(b.`title`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(b.`title`,'pear','')))/LENGTH('pear'),0) + 
    COALESCE((LENGTH(b.`title`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(b.`title`,'in-ear','')))/LENGTH('in-ear'),0) + 
    COALESCE((LENGTH(b.`title`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(b.`title`,'earphones','')))/LENGTH('earphones'),0) AS total_matches,
FROM blog b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT blog_id, COUNT(*) as matches 
    FROM tags 
    WHERE tag in ('pear', 'in-ear', 'earphones') 
    GROUP BY blog_id
) t
ON t.blog_id = b.blog_id
ORDER BY total_matches desc
ORDER BY
```

Just a note this query will probably be pretty slow with all of these matching and things. I still recommend using an indexing software like Solr

Comment: Thanks! And what about searching for the title? Could I do that the same way? The more words match the title, the higher that one should also be shown.

Comment: Yes, the question now is do you want it weighted meaning a match in the title is worth more than a match in a tag? I'll update my answer shortly to include title search matches

Comment: Hmm.. would it also be possible to let them both weigh in the total match? So if the title has 3 matches, and the tags have 3 matches, the total "rating" would be 6. That should weigh more then a result with a title match of "2", and a tag match of "3". If that makes sense.

Comment: @JohnHeroHD, that is how it's currently set up :)

Comment: I just tried it out and it's awesome! Thanks a lot! I am just having 1 issue with it: if there is a title match, but no tag match, it does not find records. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yup, it works like a charm! Thank you for the wonderful help!

Answer (score 2):

The following query counts the number of tags that match a particular list and orders by the number of matches:

```
select b.*
from blog b join
     blog_tags bt
     on b.id = bt.blog_id
where bt.tag in ('pear', 'in-ear', 'earphones')
group by blog_id
order by COUNT(*) desc;
```

Note that the use of `like` in your original query is incorrect.  None of the tags contain the string `'pear in-ear earphones'`.